# Playing around with Vigenere and Caesar cipher - Java command line encryption program

Tags: java, caesar-cipher, vigenere-cipher

I came along these two ciphers in my cryptography book and though I'd implement them just for fun. After that I went on developing a cipher based on these two that minimize the weakness of each cipher alone.
I would appreciate your expert opinions on it and if it would be possible to crypt-analyse.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class CaesarCipher{
static String encrypt(String s, int key){
List<Character> arr = Arrays.asList('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
int index;
for(int i = 0; i< s.length(); i++)
{
if(arr.contains(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i))) == false)
    str.append(s.charAt(i));
else{
index = arr.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)));
str.append(arr.get(Math.abs(index + key) % arr.size()));
   }
}

return str.toString();
}

}
class VigenereCaesar{

static String encrypt(String s, String k, int h){
List<Character> arr = Arrays.asList('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
Random rand = new Random(h);
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
int index1, index2;
int hash = h;
String key = k;
for(int i = 0; i< s.length(); i++)
{
  if(i % k.length() == 0){
   key = CaesarCipher.encrypt(key,++hash);
   Collections.shuffle(arr,rand);
  }
 if(arr.contains(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i))) == false)
  str.append(s.charAt(i));
 else{
 index1 = arr.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)));
 index2 = arr.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(key.charAt(i % key.length())));
 str.append(arr.get((index1 + index2) % arr.size()));
 }
 }

return str.toString();
}
static String encryptFile(BufferedReader buff, String k,int h) throws IOException{
List<Character> arr = Arrays.asList('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
Random rand = new Random(h);
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
int index1, index2;
int hash = h;
String key = k;
String input = buff.readLine();
int count = 0;
while(input != null){
for(int i = 0; i< input.length(); i++)
{
  if(count % k.length() == 0){
  key = CaesarCipher.encrypt(key,++hash);
  Collections.shuffle(arr,rand);
}
  if(arr.contains(Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i))) == false)
  str.append(input.charAt(i));
 else{
    index1 = arr.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i)));
    index2 = arr.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(key.charAt(i % key.length())));
    str.append(arr.get((index1 + index2) % arr.size()));
    }
    count++;
  }
  str.append("\n");
  input = buff.readLine();
 }
 return str.toString();
 }
 static String decrypt(String s, String k,int h){
 List<Character> arr = Arrays.asList('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
 Random rand = new Random(h);
 StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
 int index1, index2;
 int hash = h;
 String key = k;
 for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
 {

  if(i % key.length() == 0){
  key = CaesarCipher.encrypt(key,++hash);
  Collections.shuffle(arr,rand);
 }
 if(arr.contains(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i))) == false)
  str.append(s.charAt(i));
else{
index1 = arr.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)));
index2 = arr.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(key.charAt(i % key.length())));
str.append(arr.get((index1 + (arr.size() - index2) )% arr.size()));
System.out.println(s.charAt(i) + " ---> " + arr.get((index1 + (arr.size() - index2) )% arr.size()));
}
}

 return str.toString();
}

static String decryptFile(BufferedReader buff, String k,int h) throws IOException{
List<Character> arr = Arrays.asList('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',' ','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
Random rand = new Random(h);
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
int index1, index2;
int hash = h;
String key = k;
String input = buff.readLine();
int count = 0;
while(input!= null){
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
{
    if(count % key.length() == 0){
    key = CaesarCipher.encrypt(key,++hash);
    Collections.shuffle(arr,rand);
    }
    if(arr.contains(Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i))) == false)
    str.append(input.charAt(i));
    else{
    index1 = arr.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i)));
    index2 = arr.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(key.charAt(i % key.length())));
    str.append(arr.get((index1 + (arr.size() - index2) )% arr.size()));
    }
        count++;
    }
    str.append("\n");
    input = buff.readLine();
   }
  return str.toString();
  }
}
 public class MyCipher{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  if(args.length == 2){
    try{
     BufferedReader fileBuff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));

  if(!args[1].equals("encrypt") && !args[1].equals("decrypt")){
    System.out.println("Error Usage:\n- Encryption: java MyCipher fileName encrypt\n- Decryption: java MyCipher fileName decrypt");
    System.exit(1);
   }
   if(args[1].equals("encrypt")){
    System.out.println("Enter encryption key (The longer and more random, the harder it gets to decrypt!) :");
    String key; int hash = 0;
    key = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
    System.out.println("Enter hash:");
    try{
    hash = Integer.parseInt(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine());
    }catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
    System.out.println("Hash must be a whole number.");
    System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("Encrypting file...");
    String out = VigenereCaesar.encryptFile(fileBuff,key,hash);
    try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(args[0] + " - Encrypted");
        writer.write(out);
        writer.close();
    }catch(IOException exc){
        System.out.println("Error: Could not write to file." + exc.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("File encryption complete.");
    System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("< Created by Issa Khoury. I appreciate comments at: i_kh@icloud.com >\n");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    else if(args[1].equals("decrypt")){
    System.out.println("Enter decryption key:");
    String key;
    int hash = 0;
    key = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
    System.out.println("Enter hash:");
    try{
    hash = Integer.parseInt(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine());
    }catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
    System.out.println("Hash must be a whole number.");
    System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("Decrypting file...");
    String out = VigenereCaesar.decryptFile(fileBuff,key,hash);

    try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(args[0] + "-Decrypted");
        writer.write(out);
        writer.close();
    }catch(IOException exc){
        System.out.println("Error: Could not write to file." + exc.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("File decryption complete.");
    System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("< Created by Issa Khoury. I appreciate comments at: i_kh@icloud.com >\n");
    System.exit(0);
    }   
}catch(IOException exc){
        System.out.println("Error: Cannot procces file. " + exc.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
  }
 }
  if(args.length != 1){
  System.out.println("Error Usage:\n- Encryption: java MyCipher encrypt\n- Decryption: java MyCipher decrypt");
  System.exit(1);
}
  if(args[0].equals("encrypt")){
  System.out.println("Enter encryption key (The longer and more random, the harder it gets to decrypt!) :");
  String key; int hash = 0;
  key = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
  System.out.println("Enter hash:");
  try{
  hash = Integer.parseInt(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine());
}catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
  System.out.println("Hash must be a whole number.");
  System.exit(1);
}
  System.out.print("Plaintext: ");
  String s = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
  String out = VigenereCaesar.encrypt(s,key,hash);
  System.out.println("-----------\nCiphertext: " + out);
  System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------");
  System.out.println("< Created by Issa Khoury. I appreciate comments at: i_kh@icloud.com >\n");
  System.exit(0);
}
  else if(args[0].equals("decrypt")){
  System.out.println("Enter decryption key:");
  String key;
  int hash = 0;
  key = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
  System.out.println("Enter hash:");
  try{
  hash = Integer.parseInt(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine());
}catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
  System.out.println("Hash must be a whole number.");
  System.exit(1);
}
  System.out.print("Ciphertext: ");
  String s = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
  String out = VigenereCaesar.decrypt(s,key,hash);
  System.out.println("\n-----------\nPlaintext: " + out);
  System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------");
  System.out.println("< Created by Issa Khoury. I appreciate comments at: i_kh@icloud.com >\n");
  System.exit(0);
}
  else{
  System.out.println("Error Usage:\n- Encryption: java MyCipher encrypt\n- Decryption: java MyCipher decrypt");
  System.exit(1);
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hello there and Welcome to Code Review. I added the relevant language tag and tags for the ciphers you mention. Note that the cryptography-tag is explicitly for higher-end encryption algorithms. Caesar and Vigenere are just too simple to crack to count into that tag, so I removed it :)

Comment: Regarding cryptanalysis: both the Caesar cipher and Vigenère cipher are considered trivially crackable based on letter frequency analysis. There really isn't any way to make these ciphers secure.

Comment: Yes I know their weakness, but I'm checking if the way I combined them together mask their weakness.

Comment: @200_success Vigenerè with a (truly) random key as long as the text cannot be cracked right?

Comment: Yes, if I am not mistaken also known as One Time Pad.

Comment: Added the ability to encrypt and decrypt files.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Ah okay sorry about that, just wanted to make it clear for other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Indentation and braces style

The indentation is frankly messy, and I don't think it's entirely due to the Markdown formatting.

Also, please be consistent in your braces style. For example:

```
if(arr.contains(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i))) == false)
    str.append(s.charAt(i));
else {
    index = arr.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)));
    str.append(arr.get(Math.abs(index + key) % arr.size()));
}
```

There's no need to skim on the extra `{` and `}` characters, and without them it makes scanning the code slightly harder, IMHO.

#### Negating `if` conditions

```
if(arr.contains(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i))) == false) { /* ... */ }
```

That can be better expressed in the following way without using `== false`:

```
if(!arr.contains(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)))) { /* ... */ }
```

#### Variables names

In `VigenereCaesar`:

```
static String encrypt(String s, String k, int h){ /* ... */ }
```

It's not immediately obvious what these variables represent. Using the full form is recommended.

#### Command-line parsing

You may want to consider using some [third-party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/367714/1144592) to help you parse command-line options, instead of doing yourself.

#### `try-with-resource`

You should also be using [`try-with-resource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) *once* for safe and efficient handling of your `Scanner` instance and the underlying `System.in` input stream. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        String mode = getMode(scanner);
        if (mode.equals("encrypt")) {
            String key = getKey(scanner);
            String hash = getHash(scanner);
            // do something with key and hash
        } else if (mode.equals("decrypt")) {
            // similar to above
        } else {
            // Indicate input error
        }
    }
}
```

In the methods `getMode(Scanner)`, `getKey(Scanner)` and `getHash(Scanner)`, they can simply call the appropriate methods to get user input, and `throws IOException` to propagate any I/O exceptions back to the `main()` method. Validation errors should be handled *within* the methods though, so that they can be expected to return one result.

#### Constant `List` collections

You are declaring `Arrays.asList('A', 'B', 'C', /* ... */ 'Z')` repetitively. You can consider putting it as an *unmodifiable* `public static final List<Character>` collection, and then only for the case where you want to shuffle it, create a new instance based on it to do so.

Comment: Thank you very much, so you are right about formatting errors, I am new to pasting code here and it was tedious to indent all the lines 4 spaces to make them a code snippet. And regarding the rest, yes you are right I am not following best practices because I was coding in ad hoc manner just to see the code work correctly. And about the scanner object I never used it before, I will look into it. I appreciate the time you've took to try and "parse" my code. May I have feedback if it compiled and worked correctly ?

Comment: @IssaKhoury we kind of expect code to be compilable and working correctly in the first place... does it for you? :)

Comment: Haha yes, refactoring always comes as a second stage. I tend to crush bugs first and wait till most of the features that come to my mind are implemented before looking at code design, since adding features in a small application will surely mess up the code, so do it once at a final stage.